# Export MsAccess table to Mysql

Tags: mysql, export, ms-access-2003

I need to export 30 MSACCESS tables to a MySql database.
I have already set up ODBC settings, et can export my tables to MySql by right clicking on an MSACCESS table and :Export->ODBC database.
I want to do this automatically, but I have no knowledge in VBA.

Is it possible to do it with a VBA script and not having to export tables manually one by one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples at [MSAccess_Xfer_dB_vba_syntax_samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaac10.chm4188)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Your steps would be to figure out how often this might need to be done.
Then make a procedure or better yet a class if needed more than once and single db.  This should get you thinking...